# different result running same command in function and on main - x86-64 toy_kernel

Tags: c, kernel

I'm writing my own kernel (32-bit for now) and command works if I run on main but when running on different function it behaves differently. Any idea how and why? EDIT: the problem lies in non-functioning dereference of pointers inside other functions.

```
int foo(const char *str)
{   
    *(char*)0xb8000 = *str; // clears the screen probably because of 0 padding at the end
}
extern void main() {
    const char str[4] = {'A', 'B', 'C', '\0'};
     *(char*)0xb8000 = *str; // works good
    for(int i=0;i<1000000000;i++); // for delay
    foo(str);
    for(;;);
    return;
}
```

I expected it to behave the same but it didn't

booting code is here

```
[org 0x7c00]
KERNEL_LOCATION equ 0x1000

mov [boot_disk], dl

; set up stack
xor ax, ax                          
mov es, ax
mov ds, ax
mov bp, 0x8000
mov sp, bp


// GDT loading to memory and other stuff


[bits 32]
start_protected_mode:
    mov ax, DATA_SEG
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    
    mov ebp, 0x90000        ; 32 bit stack base pointer
    mov esp, ebp

    jmp KERNEL_LOCATION


times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

makefile

```
all:
x86_64-elf-gcc -Wall -nostdlib -ffreestanding -m64 -g -c "kernel.c" -o "kernel.o"
x86_64-elf-gcc -Wall -nostdlib -ffreestanding -m64 -g -c "idt.c" -o "idt.o"
x86_64-elf-gcc -Wall -nostdlib -ffreestanding -m64 -g -c "system.c" -o "system.o"
nasm "kernel_enrty.asm" -f elf64 -o "kernel_entry.o"
nasm "start.asm" -f elf64 -o "start.o"
x86_64-elf-ld -nostdlib -o "full_kernel.bin" -Ttext 0x1000 "kernel_entry.o" "start.o" "idt.o" "system.o"  "kernel.o" -j .text --oformat binary
nasm "boot.asm" -f bin -o "boot.bin"
cat "boot.bin" "full_kernel.bin" > "everything.bin"
nasm "padding.asm" -f bin -o "padding.bin"
cat "everything.bin" "padding.bin" > "OS.bin"
```

Comment: What's this running on? How do you set up the stack? What's at the address `0xb8000`?

Comment: Try expanding on what "works good" means. I don't think we can try your code ourselves, so we have to go from your description. My point was whatever the construct in main does, passing str into a function will lose the size information so the function definitely copies only one char.

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<1000000000;i++);` is a no-op btw, it doesn't do jack and will just get discarded by the compiler. Declare `i` as `volatile` if you want it to do something.

Comment: @teapot418 first line prints A, the second one sets video memory to '\0' which it shouldn't.

Comment: There is no reason why both assignments should behave different. Unless you have a messed up setup where parameter passing does not work properly, they will both assign `'A'` to address `0xb8000`. Is your stack configured correctly? You might add a few details how you build that kernel and how you run it.

Comment: Time to go through the corresponding assembler code?

Comment: @Gerhardh i use makefile addeed in edit

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I compiled 32 bit code to 64 bit

The updated make file:

```
all:
x86_64-elf-gcc -Wall -nostdlib -ffreestanding -m32 -g -c "kernel.c" -o "kernel.o"
x86_64-elf-gcc -Wall -nostdlib -ffreestanding -m32 -g -c "idt.c" -o "idt.o"
x86_64-elf-gcc -Wall -nostdlib -ffreestanding -m32 -g -c "system.c" -o "system.o"
nasm "kernel_enrty.asm" -f elf32 -o "kernel_entry.o"
nasm "start.asm" -f elf32 -o "start.o"
x86_64-elf-ld -nostdlib -o "full_kernel.bin" -Ttext 0x1000 "kernel_entry.o" "start.o" "idt.o" "system.o"  "kernel.o"  --oformat binary -m elf_i386
nasm "boot.asm" -f bin -o "boot.bin"
cat "boot.bin" "full_kernel.bin" > "everything.bin"
nasm "padding.asm" -f bin -o "padding.bin"
cat "everything.bin" "padding.bin" > "OS.bin"
```